# XMLDocument.Save adds return carriages to XML when elements are blank

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm loading a XML Document that has some tags that have no innertext.

If I populate the innertext with some data then it works as needed (you get opening tag, innertext and closing tag all on one line) like the following...

```
<root>
  <element>value</element>
</root>
```

The problem arises with tags with no values. These SHOULD be displayed in the same way as above with the exception of no value of coarse, like the following...

```
<root>
  <element></element>
</root>
```

However, when the innertext has an empty string it adds a carriage return & line feed which is not what is expected!  It ends up looking like the following...

```
<root>
  <element>
  </element>
</root>
```

**This is my current code that yields the above results...**

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\test.xml");

//Save the xml and then cleanup
xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\test.xml");
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This fixed it for me...

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\test.xml");

//Save the xml and then cleanup
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\test.xml", settings);
xmlDoc.Save(writer);
```

Comment: I don't understand why this works and the XmlDocument PreserveWhiteSpace keeps failing me, but it solved my problem.

Comment: This helped us with an issue we were having causing a database not to build correctly from a modified xml output.  The issue was the new lines generated from the 'XmlDocument.Save()' method on empty elements.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You control that through the XMLWriter within the Settings Property.

Check out this example along with the following references.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162618.aspx

Refernces
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.newlinehandling.aspx

Comment: Thanks, yea I found my answer as soon as I posted this question.  I submitted the exact code to help others out if they run into the same situation.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late, but I referred to the solution given by Arvo Bowen. 
Arvo's solution is in C#, I wrote the same in Powershell Syntax

```
# $dest_file is the path to the destination file
$xml_dest = [XML] (Get-Content $dest_file)

#
#   Operations done on $xml_dest
#

$settings = new-object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$settings.CloseOutput = $true
$settings.Indent = $true
$writer = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($dest_file, $settings)

$xml_dest.Save($writer)
$writer.Close()
```

It solved my two problems:

- One, problem stated above i.e. newline character being added to null/empty values.
- Second, no end tag being created for null/empty values.
  ex: `<tag1>$null</tag1>` would actually be written in file as `<tag />`
  Refer this thread: 
  [Can we force XmlWriter to issue <my-tag></my-tag> rather than <my-tag/>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010420/can-we-force-xmlwriter-to-issue-my-tag-my-tag-rather-than-my-tag)